# How to extract values from the response data of several threads, Soap project

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to extract data from the response:

```
  <ns2:MensajeRta>
        <SCodigoRespuesta/>
        <BOperacionExitosa>true</BOperacionExitosa>
        <SIdentificadorProceso/>
        <SMensajeRtaUsuario>Transaccion Exitosa</SMensajeRtaUsuario>
        <SMensajeRtaTecnico/>
    </ns2:MensajeRta>
    <ns2:Lineas>
        <BTieneFiduColombia>false</BTieneFiduColombia>
        <LineasFinanciacion>
            <Linea>
                <idPLineaFinanciacion>BCINB006</idPLineaFinanciacion>
                <FPorcentaje>0.0</FPorcentaje>
                <IdRegla>RNPS62</IdRegla>
            </Linea>
            <Linea>
                <idPLineaFinanciacion>PRINP074</idPLineaFinanciacion>
                <FPorcentaje>1.0</FPorcentaje>
                <IdRegla>RNPS11</IdRegla>
            </Linea>
        </LineasFinanciacion>
    </ns2:Lineas>
</ns2:ConsultaPrescoringResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 options:

- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) using XPath to extract data
- [Regex Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) using Regex
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) using syntax like this:

  - https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
  - Have a look at:

    > ns|tag: find elements by tag in a namespace, e.g. fb|name finds  elements

Depending on what you're most comfortable with make your choice.

You'll need to add this component as a child of the HTTP Request that contains your SOAP Request. This will extract a variable (name it as you want in extractor) that you can later use with this syntax ${varName}

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable choice given you are getting response in XML form would be [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor). It allows executing arbitrary [XPath Queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) to get the values of certain nodes, attributes, etc.

For example, XPath query to get `Transaccion Exitosa` value would be as simple as `//idPLineaFinanciacion/text()`

Demo (you can test your XPath queries directly in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener):

[image: JMeter Xpath Extractor Demo]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)